# Caching assets in website served from GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages, configuration, cache

The server for GitHub pages (including mine) sets `CacheControl: max-age=600`. It means the cache is set to last only for [ten minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), which is undesirable.

Is it possible to control this value and to set also `only-if-cached` status?

I know that there is no direct access to the `.htaccess` file or an equivalent, but I am looking for indirect access via some sort of settings or confirmation, or proof that it is impossible.

[image]

Note: this question is not a duplicate of [Caching assets in Github pages (github.io)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/caching-assets-in-github-pages-github-io) which answers whether Github pages have any caching at all.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Officially confirmed to be impossible.

Answer from GitHub support:

> Thanks for reaching out to GitHub Support about using GitHub Pages
>
> We set the following Cache-Control header for all GitHub Pages content:
>
> `Cache-Control: max-age=600`
>
> This header is the same for all assets on all sites on our Pages service, and we don't currently provide a way to alter the value.
>
> I hope that this answers your questions.

Comment: what the hell is this nonsense...

Comment: @Rotem You can try contacting them, maybe it changed or they will change it if enough people will ask. But AFAIK main recent change is removal of ability to contact employees.

Comment: @reducingactivity is there a feature request we can vote on? Or any recommended way to request this change?

Comment: @MominBinShahid I am not aware about Microsoft having some place where feedback about GitHub can be send and would be treated seriously.

Comment: Thanks, @reducingactivity, will update here if anything similar is introduced in future 